# Batch scripting for directories or better method

Tags: c#, wpf, batch-file, echo, mkdir

Looking at creating a simple batch file for my app. My app needs some directories to be in place as it runs.

The first method I thought was just make a batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST C:\App GOTO :CREATE ELSE GOTO :DONTCREATE

:CREATE
MKDIR C:\App\Code
ECHO DIRECTORY CREATED

:DONTCREATE
ECHO IT WAS ALREADY THERE
```

1) This doesn't run as I would expect. Both `:CREATE` and `:DONTCREATE` seem to run regardless? How do I do an If properly then?

Output:

```
A subdirectory or file C:\App\Code already exists.
DIRECTORY CREATED
IT WAS ALREADY THERE
```

So it enters both true and false statements?

<del>2) The app is a C# WPF app. For what I am trying to do here (create a couple of directories if they don't already exist) - should I do it some other way? Perhaps in the application as it runs?</del>

**edit**: Ok, happy to just do in C# code - but can anyone explain the problem with my batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is perhaps that you think of the GOTO targets as method start points. They are just labels in the file. This means that after

```
IF NOT EXIST C:\App GOTO :CREATE ELSE GOTO :DONTCREATE
```

execution picks up with

```
:CREATE
```

and then continues on down the script right through

```
:DONTCREATE
```

until the end of the file is reached. You have to add another GOTO if you want to go somewhere else after :CREATE finishes. The usual case is to tell it to GOTO :EOF (a built-in label) at the end, as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST C:\App GOTO :DONTCREATE

:CREATE
MKDIR C:\App\Code
ECHO DIRECTORY CREATED
GOTO :EOF

:DONTCREATE
ECHO IT WAS ALREADY THERE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do all the directory stuff directly in C#, if that would be easier:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(@"c:\app\code")
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\app\code");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("Directory already exists!");
}
```

See this page for more info:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa70yfe2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer is probably what you've already thought of - to create the directory from the application as it runs.

[DirectoryInfo.Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d869eykc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is the method you'll need.